# Hide Navigation Bar after dismiss controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, dismiss

hello I have **ControllerA** in which I am hiding a `NavigationBar`. On the **ControllerB** I am showing the `NavigationBar`. On the ControllerB I have implemented a searchBar with `TableView`. So when user selects any row I am dismissing the controller. Problem is It shows navigationBar on controllerA.

This is how I am first hiding the NavigationBar in ControllerA

**ControllerA**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated);

     self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)

}
```

**ControllerB** here I am showing it

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated);
            self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
        }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

 self.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

What I have tried is I try to put hidden navigation Code in `viewWillDisappear` function in ControllerB but it doesn't work. It hides the bar in some delay after showing it.
 I also tried to put in the `viewDidLoad` function of ControllerA, But still it shows the bar

Please tell me how can I hide the navigationBar on ControllerA after  **ControllerB** get dismissed

Comment: set hidden navigation bar in viewDidDisappear in controller B?

Comment: It didn't work. still showing

Comment: hide the navigation bar in viewDidAppear in controller A.

Comment: PGDev's answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: @PGDev well it removes but after some delay. it shows for 1 2 second

Comment: I tried with viewWillAppear in both Controller A and Controller B and its working fine for me. viewDidAppear will surely give some delay.

Comment: use dispatch_async instead.

Comment: dispatch_async in which function and in which controller?

Comment: Why you use `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)` ? This will hide navigationBar instantly.

Comment: @Dudi done that too.. still no luck

Answer (score 3):

you can use notification post a notification on **controllerB** in view will Diss Appear and recive it in ControllerA .and at ControllerA in the selector method of notification write code to hide navigationbar .

write this code in view will disappear in **controllerB**-

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NotificationIdentifierForHideNavigationBar", object: nil)
```

write this code in controller

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "methodOfReceivedNotificationHideBar:", name:"NotificationIdentifierForHideNavigationBar", object: nil)
```

Use these method:-

```
   func methodOfReceivedNotificationHideBar(notification: NSNotification){
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)     
  }
```

try this as written

Comment: b,coz when we dismiss a contoller and back previous controller then viewwill apper and viewdid appear not called

Comment: if we want to perform action on previous controller we have to use custom delegate

Comment: @punitalex Dismiss and pop are two different behavouir. don't mix it. And both of these methods gets on pop. So Notification is good way but for this example no need to use it.

Comment: @ Ashok Londhe ok its my mistake i focus only when  – "user1hjgjhgjhggjhg" write " I am dismissing the controller" and not see code clearly i think he is present not pop

Answer (score 2):

In the first view controller `viewWillAppear()`, add this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

 self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
 }
```

In the second one, add this:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

      self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
 }




override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {

     self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in **ControllerA**

**Code:**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
     self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

It is working fine for me... Try it ...!!!

Comment: @user1hjgjhgjhggjhg Remove all other methods and code from controllerA and then try its working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Its so simple
In first view controller viewWillAppear() add code

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
     self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true);
}
```

In second view controller add following code

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true);
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true);
}
```

OutPut Result: FirstViewcontroller without navigation bar
[image]

Second view controller with navigation bar
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this entiere code? Beacues I use those two ViewControllers

**ViewControllerA**

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**TableViewControllerA**

```
class TableViewControllerA: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = "test"

        return cell
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}
```

This is how it look like. [YT](https://youtu.be/NQ5u7uXNYOM)